# How to import data into MongoDB from another MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I've installed new MongoDB server and now I want to import data from the old one. My MongoDB stores monitoring data and it's a bit problematic to export the data from old database (it's over 10Gb), so I though it might be possible to import directly from DB, but haven't found how to do that with mongoimport.

Comment: A very important question: is the data set on the old database static? Or are there still writes to it?

Comment: @wdberkeley yes, data in the old database is static. and it will be only one time import. I just had to start using the new server and didn't have time to copy from the old server

Comment: You could just copy the data files directly (if the versions are the same, otherwise check the release notes) or use mongodump and mongorestore. DON'T use mongoimport/mongoexport as those produce/consume JSON which does not preserve all the type information in BSON.

Answer (score 1):

The export/import would be the fastest option.

But if you really want to bypass it you can use the new server as a replica of the old one, and wait for  full replication.
It takes longer but it's an easy way to set up a full copy without impact on the first one.

Follow this:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/convert-standalone-to-replica-set/

And then, once it's done, change configuration again.

It's easiest than it seems, but I recommend you to do a dry run with a sample database before doing it...

Note that another benefit is that the new replica will be probably smaller in size than the initial database, because MongoDb is not very good at freeing space of deleted members

Comment: Why remove the replica set? Add / keep an arbiter and you have failover capabilities.

Comment: sure @MarkusWMahlberg but I was just trying to answer to the inital quesiton. May be you need the first machine for a different reason....

Answer (score 1):

`mongoimport/mongoexport` is per collection operating, so it's not proper for this kind of operation.
Instead to use `mongodump/mongorestore`.

If the old MongoDB instance can be shutdown to do this task, you can shut down it then copy all data files to the new server as its own data. And run the new instance.

Also `db.cloneDatabase()` can handle it to copy data directly from old instance to new one. It should be slower against copying data files directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mongodump` and pipe directly to the new database with `mongorestore` like:
`mongodump --archive --db=test | mongorestore --archive  --nsFrom='test.*' --nsTo='examples.*'`
add `--host` `--port` and `--username` to `mongorestore` to connect to the remote db.
`db.cloneDatabase()` has been deprecated for a while.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `copydb` command [discribed here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/copydb/).

Copies a database from a remote host to the current host or copies a database to another database within the current host.
copydb runs on the destination mongod instance, i.e. the host receiving the copied data.